# Faraday's law and potential along a closed curve

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields, calculus

$$\int(\nabla \times \vec{E}) \cdot d\vec{S} = \oint \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l} = -\frac{\mathrm{d} \phi_b}{\mathrm{d} t}$$
The second expression is the potential difference along a closed curve. Isn't this just zero? Because you've started and ended at the same point.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not zero. It would have been zero had it been a conservative force e.g. gravity, electric field due to a conductor (electrostatic). 
 But this field is *induced electric field* $\vec E$ produced due to changing magnetic flux and this field is non-conservative in nature. 
 Hence like non-conservative forces, line integral around a closed loop is not zero .$$\oint \vec E \cdot\ d\vec l \not = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all. Imagine doing the line integral of a vector field around a square path. Now envisage that the vector field varies in magnitude and/or direction with position. There is no particular reason that the line integral along one side of the square should cancel with that on the opposite side.

In fact, the expression of Stokes's theorem that you used to write the first equality in your equation hints at when the closed line integral will be non-zero. It's when you have a field with a non-zero curl such that the "flux" of this curl over the area bounded by the closed loop is also non-zero.

In electromagnetism this situation arises when you have a "source of curl". For an E-field this is a changing magnetic field, whilst for B-fields it is a changing electric field and/or a current. In the *absence* of these "sources", the curls of E- and B-fields *are* zero.

It struck me that you are probably now thinking, but why if I have a uniformly changing magnetic flux through a loop should that necessarily produce a net line integral, with an implied asymmetry of the electric field?

That is the wrong way to think about these things. The electric field is not produced by the changing flux, the two co-exist - an E-field will always circulate around a changing B-field, producing non-zero curl and a non-zero closed line integral.

Comment: That makes sense. I see your point about how the line integral needn't necessarily be zero. However, in this case does the line integral still represent a potential difference? I mean if you took two ends of a voltmeter and connected it to the same point on the closed loop(made of wire), would the voltmeter register a non-zero reading?

Comment: @IanDsouza You can't measure a p.d. if dl=0. To measure the full pd around the loop you would need to put a break in the wire and attach the meter to each end.